# How to debug a syntax error in a MySQL SQL statement?

Tags: php, sql

My code shows the following error, I did not understand how to correct it:

> you have an error in your sql syntax, check the manual corresponds to your mysql server version for the right syntax to use near ')'at line 1

```
$query="insert into subjective_result(marks,roll_no)values($marks,$roll)";     
mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Why are you using **mysql_\*** deprecated methods?, you should use **mysqli_\*** methods.

Comment: give proper spaces in your mysql query. Change it to `$query="insert into subjective_result(marks,roll_no) values($marks,$roll)";    `

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions (and especially to titles, where it will irritate users all the more).

Answer (score 2):

Because you didn't escaped the inputs it should be

```
$query="insert into subjective_result(marks,roll_no)values('$marks','$roll')";
```

Anyway this is not the best way to do that, you have to use prepared statement and wrapper such as [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). If you concatenate your own queries you are likely to run into a SQL injection vulnerability.

Something like this

```
    // didn't test it
    $stmt = $db->prepare('insert into subjective_result(marks,roll_no)values(:marks,:roll_no)');
    $stmt->bindValue(":marks", $marks);
    $stmt->bindValue(":roll_no", $roll_no);

    if ($stmt->execute()) {
      //code here
    }
```

Comment: Three answers, only one thinks to mention parameter binding. Good work!

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$query="insert into subjective_result(`marks`,`roll_no`)values(".$marks.",".$roll.")";
```

It's recommended to always wrap the column names in your SQL statements with "`" (the backtick character, which is often the key over the Tab key).

Also, `$marks` and `$roll` are variables, and they can't be inserted in a string like a normal text, so you have to concatenate them with your string query.

Comment: This may fix the immediate bug, but it will likely get a SQL injection vulnerability working as well.